# Assign Ids to a paired group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table with some asset information that looks like this:

```
| ID |  PairID | AssetName   | PairAssetName | 
|----|---------|-------------|---------------|
|  1 | 3       | Case1       | Case3         |
|  4 | 2       | Case4       | Case2         |
|  3 | 1       | Case3       | Case1         |
|  2 | 4       | Case2       | Case4         |
```

As you can see the ID and the PairIDs are related one to another with data on the same table. I need to assign a group ID that allows me to identify them in an incremental way. Something that looks like this:

```
| ID |  PairID | AssetName   | PairAssetName| GroupID |
|----|---------|-------------|--------------|---------|
|  1 | 3       | Case1       | Case3        | Group1  |
|  4 | 2       | Case4       | Case2        | Group2  |
|  3 | 1       | Case3       | Case1        | Group1  |
|  2 | 4       | Case2       | Case4        | Group2  |
```

Which will allow me to identify pairs in an easier way, knowing that sometimes, some rows won't have a pair at all. Is there a way to do this in SQL? It doesn't need to say Group1 but with the number would be more than enough.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: oh sorry, I though I selected only sql server tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an integer is sufficient for the `groupid`, then one method is `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by case when id < pairid then id else pairid end,
                                   case when id < pairid then pairid else id end
                         ) as groupid                                   
from t;
```

Comment: the problem here is that the Ids might not be in sequential order. 1 can be paired with 5, and 7 can be paired with 13, for example. The only thing is that every ID can be paired to another one or none.

Comment: @JesusRincon . . . I get that.  This assigns a unique number to each pair.

Comment: works like a charm! Can I ask what is it exactly doing with that case? I tried to use the dense_rank but it didn't work for me

Comment: @JesusRincon . . . This does the `dense_rank()` on the least and greatest of the two ids.  Those values are the same when the ids are the same (in either order).